# A condition under which an Lp function is L-infinity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

I am looking for a condition under which a function in $L_p(\Omega)$ is also in $L_\infty(\Omega)$. The condition may be on the function itself, or on $\Omega$.

In other words, is there anything that guarantees a p-integrable function is bounded?

Comment: As far as $\Omega$, this holds iff $\Omega$ is a union of atoms whose measures are bounded below.  It has to look roughly like a discrete set with counting measure.  See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9692/when-l-p-l-q/9741#9741,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994518/when-do-lp-and-lq-contain-the-same-functions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266213/does-one-of-l-infty-and-lp-p-in-0-infty-contain-the-other?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Or maybe the question is about a *single* function in $L_p$—the quantifiers aren't clear—in which case there probably isn't much better answer to when it's in $L_\infty$ than that it's essentially bounded.

Comment: sufficiently many weak derivatives in $L^p$?

Comment: Also: $f$ is in $L_\infty$ of and only if $fg$ is integrable for any integrable $g$

Comment: It is a very vague question. You should let us know everything you are happy to assume about said function / domain.

Answer (score 1):

There is a necessary and sufficient condition. It goes as follows:

Let $f$ be in $L^p$, or even just $L_{loc}^1$. Given a non null measurable subset $A$ of $\Omega$, define the measure space $\mathbf{A} := (A, \mathcal F_A, \nu_A)$ where $\mathcal F_A $ is the induced sigma algebra, and $\nu_A$ is the normalised induced measure given by $\nu_A (E) = \frac{\mu(E \cap A)}{\mu(A)}$.

Given any $f, A$ as above, define $f_A$ to be the function on $\mathbf{A}$ given by $f_A (x) = \frac{ f(x)}{\mu(A)}$.

Let $\mathcal D$ denote the family of non-null $G_{\delta}$ subsets of $\Omega$. Then we have the following:

**Theorem:** $f$ is in $L^ \infty$ if and only if the family $\{f_A\}_{A \in \mathcal D}$ is uniformly integrable.

*Note: The condition that $\mathcal D$ consists of all non-null $G_\delta$ sets can be signifcantly relaxed.*

Answer (score 1):

You can also use integrability of derivatives, i.e. apply Sobolev embedding: If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then it holds that the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ embeds into $L^\infty(\Omega)$ (even into the continuous and bounded functions), if
$$\tfrac{n}{k}\leq p.$$
In other words: For an $L^p$ function to be bounded, you also need that the derivatives of order up to $n/p$ are also $p$-integrable. For example, in one dimension, $W^{1,1}$ embeds into $L^\infty$, i.e. an integrable function with integrable weak derivative also also bounded.